# bitcoin payment using Blocktrail?

Tags: php, blocktrail

I am integrating blocktrail api in my web application and i am new to bitcoin.
I created new account in blocktrail,and created new wallet.And it is 0.00000000 tBTC  now.
Will you please tell me how to make payment using this blocktrail?
I foud the code in https://www.blocktrail.com/api/docs/lang/php#receiving_transactions.But How to transfer bitcoin to our merchant account from client?

-error is coming "Uncaught exception **strong text**'Blocktrail\SDK\Connection\Exceptions\EndpointSpecificError' with message 'Wallet balance too low'";

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab some testnet coins in your new wallet. You can get them from any [number](https://accounts.blockcypher.com/testnet-faucet) [of](http://www.bitcointestnetfaucet.com/) [testnet](http://tpfaucet.appspot.com/) [faucets](http://faucet.xeno-genesis.com/).